# Only the first customUIView is added in the scrollView

Tags: ios, swift

i set like this
'''

```
@IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!

lazy var vs = [v0, v1, v2]

lazy var v0: MyCleanTabPageView = {//This is My Custom UIView
    let view = MyCleanTabPageView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()

func setScroll() {
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scroll.isPagingEnabled = true
    scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(vs.count), height: v0.frame.height)
    for i in 0..<vs.count{
        scroll.addSubview(vs[i])
        vs[i].frame = CGRect(x: vs[i].frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width , height: view.frame.height)
    }
    scroll.delegate = self
}
```

'''
[first scroll View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmipP.png)

but the only first customView is added in the scroll View.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check view hiearchy on debug tab and make sure just one custom view added.

And after added custom view, you have to set constraints to activate scrool view. You can add custom constraint to like this,

```swift
if i == 0 {
    vs[i].leftAnchor.constaint(to: scroolView.leftAchor).isActive = true
} else {
    vs[i].leftAnchor.constaint(to: v[i -1].leftAchor).isActive = true
}
vs[i].topAnchor.constaint(to: scroolView.topAnchor).isActive = true
vs[i].bottomAnchor.constaint(to: scroolView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

if i == vs.count -1 {
    vs[i].right.constaint(to: scroolView.right).isActive = true
}
```

Your function should be shown like this;

```swift
func setScroll() {
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
scroll.isPagingEnabled = true
scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(vs.count), height: v0.frame.height)

  for i in 0..<vs.count {
      vs[i].frame = CGRect(x: vs[i].frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width , height: view.frame.height)
      vs[i].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      scroll.addSubview(vs[i])
      if i == 0 {
          vs[i].leftAnchor.constaint(to: scroolView.leftAchor).isActive = true
      } else {
          vs[i].leftAnchor.constaint(to: v[i -1].leftAchor).isActive = true
      }
      vs[i].topAnchor.constaint(to: scroolView.topAnchor).isActive = true
      vs[i].bottomAnchor.constaint(to: scroolView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

      if i == vs.count -1 {
        vs[i].right.constaint(to: scroolView.right).isActive = true
      }
  }
    scroll.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: I forgot to write something. You should set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. I edited my answer. Can you try one more time if your problem still continues.

Comment: haha i already added that line. but ... didn't work